# AutoMocking Properties Fails on Abstract Property?

Tags: c#, xunit.net, autofixture, nsubstitute

I'm trying to learn AutoFixture, and I've got xUnit and NSubstitute and AutoFixture setup to automatically mock out properties with fakes (with AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute).  In other words, if I have the following interface

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IBar1 Bar1 {get;}
    IBar2 Bar2 {get; set;}
}
```

Trying to resolve an IFoo will automatically resolve and populate Bar1 and Bar2.

Everything works great for objects with properties of interface, concrete object, or structure types.  I'm having a problem getting AutoFixture to automatically create properties of abstract types however.

I have tried using a TypeRelay for the abstract type, so

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof (AbstractBase), typeof (ConcreteChild)));
```

I have tried specifying it this way,

```
fixture.Customize<AbstractBase>(
            composer =>
                composer.FromFactory(
                    (string ChildParam1, string ChildParam2) => new ConcreteChild(ConcreteChildParam1, ConcreteChildParam2)));
```

I have tried using various custom specimen builders

Resolving via the property type:

```
var pi = request as PropertyInfo;

if (pi != null &&
    pi.PropertyType == typeof(AbstractBase))
    return context.Resolve(typeof(ConcreteChild));

return new NoSpecimen(request);
```

Resolving via the class type:

```
var pi = request as Type;

if (pi != null &&
    pi == typeof (AbstractBase))
    return context.Resolve(typeof(ConcreteChild));

return new NoSpecimen(request);
```

With both of the above solutions, I also tried `context.Create<ConcreteChild>()`

Finally I have tried using the `Register<AbstractBase>(fixture.Create<ConcreteChild>);` syntax.

None of them seem to work as far as automatically populating properties on an object.

The irritating thing is that I can explicitly `fixture.Create<AbstractBase>();` in an individual test and get the `ConcreteChild` and then hand-jam everything but that kind of defeats the purpose of AutoFixture no?

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The abstract class.  I've pruned most of the irrelivent stuff, left the ctor code in as I'm assuming it gets called?

```
public abstract class ChatEntityId 
{
    private string _localName;

    protected ChatEntityId(string chatRoomName, string entityUid, ChatProtocol protocol)
    {
        ErrorChecker.NormalizeToNullIfNotSet(ref chatRoomName);
        ErrorChecker.NormalizeToNullIfNotSet(ref entityUid);
        if (chatRoomName == null && entityUid == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Both chatRoomName and entityUid may not be null at the same time.");
        }

        ChatRoomName = chatRoomName;
        EntityUid = entityUid;
        Protocol = protocol;
    }

    public string ChatRoomName { get; private set; }

    public string EntityUid { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(ChatEntityId chatEntityId) { }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) { }

    public override int GetHashCode() {}

    public string LocalName { get; }

    public ChatProtocol Protocol { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString() { }
}
```

`ChatProtocol` is an enum, fairly standard.

**The AutoPopulatedProperty ICustomization**

```
    public virtual void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize(new DomainCustomization());

        // Replacement for the AutoNSubstituteCustomization, this Postprocessor will automatically create fake objects on properties.
        fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(
            new Postprocessor(
                new NSubstituteBuilder(
                    new MethodInvoker(
                        new NSubstituteMethodQuery())),
                new AutoPropertiesCommand(
                    new PropertiesOnlySpecification())));
    }

    private class PropertiesOnlySpecification : IRequestSpecification
    {
        public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
        {
            return request is PropertyInfo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for the abstract type?

Comment: Updated.  I'm not necessarily sure if I'm explaining the actual problem (which I'm not sure about) clearly, I had a thought/realization yesterday and the way I thought AutoFixture was working may be a mistaken assumption. I assumed the Postprocessor for autopopulating fake objects would circle back and make requests from the fixture, but I'm not sure that it's doing it?  I've added the code I yanked from somewhere else for having AutoNSubstitute auto-mock properties.

Comment: Does [this gist](https://gist.github.com/moodmosaic/11558c7db2c6bfac971a) reproduce your case?

Comment: If that gist reproduces the case, it looks like a limitation of interaction between AutoFixture and NSubstitute. It may be similar to [this AutoMoq behaviour](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/05/how-to-configure-automoq-to-set-up-all-properties), but I don't know what the default NSubstitute behaviour for properties is...

Comment: Yes, exactly. BTW, I also don't know much about the default behavior of NSubstitute. OOTB, right now only AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy passes both tests in the gist.

Comment: Yes, that looks accurate and I get the same test results.  However for clarification, the abstract property class is not a generic abstract.  Just making sure we aren't going down the path of thinking its a generic abstract type resolution problem or something (though maybe it's all the same thing as far as how autofixture/nsubstitute work, not my area of expertise :))

Comment: AFAICT, there are at least two options. Try to apply [this AutoMoq behavior](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/05/how-to-configure-automoq-to-set-up-all-properties) with NSubstitute, or use [AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy) which supports this specific interaction.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the AutoPopulatedProperty ICustomization I have up there is the same thing as the AutoMoq behavior?

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis I re-read and re-ran your gist except without the 'default' NSubstitute customization and with the one I have posted above and both of them instead now pass, so not sure what that tells you.

Comment: @Greg Can you leave a comment on the gist with the code you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat embarrassingly, I realized that NSubstitute has what it calls [*recursive mocking*](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/auto-and-recursive-mocks/), which is partially what I want and explains why I couldn't figure out where some of the auto-mocked properties were coming from.  The problem is that it doesn't do it across the board (probably rightfully so), and isn't really extensible in that regard as far as I can tell.

Now AutoFixture comes into play, after we create the specimen in the Postprocessors `NSubstituteBuilder`, the `AutoPropertiesCommand` class is called and fetches what it determines are the appropriate properties to populate with data.

Unfortunately none of the logic in the two relevant classes (there is a non-generic inheriting from a generic `AutoPropertiesCommand` class) is overridable and this is where the problem occurs.  Specifically, `AutoPropertiesCommand<T>` has two methods it uses to get properties and fields, which it then filters using the supplied `IRequestSpecification` (`PropertiesOnlySpecification` in this case).

The method in question

```
    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(object specimen)
    {
        return from pi in this.GetSpecimenType(specimen).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               where pi.GetSetMethod() != null
               && pi.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0
               && this.specification.IsSatisfiedBy(pi)
               select pi;
    }
```

So the solution here is to either provide my own `AutoPropertiesCommand` implementation without the above limitations or explicitly create customizations for each case I run across.  Haven't decided which approach I like better but probably the former.

As a side-bar it seems kind of restrictive to not have those two methods as protected virtual, is there any particular reason for this beyond "it was just coded that way"?  Those are base AutoFixture classes I believe, for the record.